# Unable to trace in spring boot 3 when using SQS Queue

Tags: spring-boot, trace, open-telemetry, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm using openTelemetry and Micrometer as tracing system for my current project. I have a SQS queue from which I'm consuming the message using `@SqsListener`. While processing the message few other api calls are made to other services as part of processing. When I'm looking at the logs, I'm able to see the traceId being populated for the api calls. But I'm not able to see any traceId when consuming the message from the SQS Queue.

I also tried creating a span myself when consuming the message thinking that it might be the issue

```
@SqsListener(
            value = "${amazon.sqs.queueName}",
            deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void consumeEvent(Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Span span =
                tracer
                        .spanBuilder()
                        .name("name")
                        .start();
        tracer.withSpan(span);
        try {
            // message processing code
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            tracer.currentSpan().end();
        }
    }
```

but this too isn't working for me.

Comment: SQS is not instrumented (yet), you can try to instrument on your own or add a comment/thumbsup to this issue to help prioritizing it: https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/issues/646